# End(xlUp) only works when the sheet is acive

Tags: excel, range, vba

I have following code

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook`

ComboBox7.RowSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A2", _
Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).Address
```

If I don't put `wb.Sheets("Sheet5").Select` before this line, this code throws error

`"Application defined or object-defined error"`

I want this code to work without selecting the Sheet5.

If I put `ComboBox7.RowSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A2:A7").Address` then it works fine without selecting the sheet5.

Is there any way to use `End(xlUp)` without selecting the sheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

**Logic**: Find the last row and then use that to create a range which you can assign to your combobox.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet5")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    End With

    ComboBox5.RowSource = rng.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: I will be using this thing in many places. If i convert this to a function, how can I pass the Column name to this function and use it in the function?

Comment: Will it be from the same sheet always?

Comment: Hey the above code doesn't throw an error but it is taking the range from the sheet1 and not sheet5

Comment: Not possible :) What have you specified here? `Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet5")`?

Comment: May I see your file? It is technically impossible for the code to set the range to Sheet1 if you have specified Sheet5

Comment: The selected sheet is `Sheet1` tha'ts why its taking `range` from `Sheet1`. I debugged it the `lRow` is coming correct according to the data in Sheet5 but in `combobox` it is showing values from `Sheet1`. Sorry i can't share the code. Are you online right now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29235/discussion-between-mayur2j-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: I prefer to use `sheet.cells.find("*", direction:=xlprevious)`

Comment: @glh: Even me too but only if I am trying to find the last row in a worksheet... not in a column. You might want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Answer (score -1):

The other thing is to do this in one line

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.sheets("sheets5")

ComboBox7.RowSource = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).Address
```

The second range thinks it is working from the active sheet, you need to tell it otherwise.

Using With is better but this is one line if you are writing code quickly just to get something done.